# CSS Animation Background-Position in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations

I'm trying to create a CSS animation that loops through 16 images in a sprite sheet that gives the illusion of a ghost "floating". The animation accomplishes this by going between `background-position` locations to show the ghost in different states.

[image]

In Chrome, Firefox and Safari it works great. In IE11 it does not.

(Browserstack testing shows it does work in Edge.)

I've read online that IE does not support animation of background-images, but this is background-*position*. Perhaps that's the problem.

Here is the code, or a JSFiddle to help: https://jsfiddle.net/nuw1ypfm/6/

```css
.ghost {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50% -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50% -50%);
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
    opacity: 0.75;
    z-index: 101;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-size: 256px 262px;
    background-position: -64px -198px;
    will-change: background-position;
    animation-name: float; 
    animation-timing-function: step-end, step-end;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    
    -webkit-animation-name: float; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: step-end, step-end;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    
    -ms-animation-name: float; 
    -ms-animation-timing-function: step-end, step-end;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-animation-duration: 5s;
    
}


@keyframes float {
 0% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 10% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 12.5% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 15% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 17.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 20% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 22.5% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 25% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 27.5% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 30% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 32.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 35% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 37.5% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 40% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 42.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 45% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 47.5% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 50% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 52.5% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 55% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 57.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 60% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 62.5% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 65% {
  background-position: 0 -2px
 }
 67.5% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 70% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 72.5% {
  background-position: -128px 2px
 }
 75% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 77.5% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 80% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 82.5% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 85% {
  background-position: -128px 2px
 }
 87.5% {
  background-position: -64px 2px
 }
 90% {
  background-position: 0 -2px
 }
 92.5% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 95% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 97.5% {
  background-position: -128px 2px
 }
 100% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes float {
 0% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 2.5% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 7.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 10% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 12.5% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 15% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 17.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 20% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 22.5% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 25% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 27.5% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 30% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 32.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 35% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 37.5% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 40% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 42.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 45% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 47.5% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 50% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 52.5% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 55% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 57.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 60% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 62.5% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 65% {
  background-position: 0 -2px
 }
 67.5% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 70% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 72.5% {
  background-position: -128px 2px
 }
 75% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 77.5% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 80% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 82.5% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 85% {
  background-position: -128px 2px
 }
 87.5% {
  background-position: -64px 2px
 }
 90% {
  background-position: 0 -2px
 }
 92.5% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 95% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 97.5% {
  background-position: -128px 2px
 }
 100% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes float {
 0% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 2.5% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 7.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 10% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 12.5% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 15% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 17.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 20% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 22.5% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 25% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 27.5% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 30% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 32.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 35% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 37.5% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 40% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 42.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 45% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 47.5% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 50% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 52.5% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 55% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 57.5% {
  background-position: 0 -133px
 }
 60% {
  background-position: -192px -131px
 }
 62.5% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 65% {
  background-position: 0 -2px
 }
 67.5% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 70% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 72.5% {
  background-position: -128px 2px
 }
 75% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
 77.5% {
  background-position: -64px -131px
 }
 80% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 82.5% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 85% {
  background-position: -128px 2px
 }
 87.5% {
  background-position: -64px 2px
 }
 90% {
  background-position: 0 -2px
 }
 92.5% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 95% {
  background-position: -192px 1px
 }
 97.5% {
  background-position: -128px 2px
 }
 100% {
  background-position: -128px -131px
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="ghost">

</div>
```

Any guidance would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: try to pass the timing function like this to check the result in IE.  -ms-animation-timing-function: steps(4, 10); Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I think there is a bug with IE11 that doesn't allow you to animate both transform positions and background-image positions. Your steps idea was a good one, and worked in jsfiddle, but once applied to my game it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried various things, but IE11 is a tricky beast. I found the best way was to create various classes and then use a JavaScript timer to loop through them. I did something like the following (I used jQuery, but I didn't have to):

```
.ghost.step1 { background-position: x y }
.ghost.step2 { background-position: x (y+5) }
.ghost.step3 { background-position: (x+5) (y+10) }
.ghost.step4 { background-position: (x+10) (y+15) }
...
.ghost.step40 { background-position: x y }

var num = 1;
var gInterval = setInterval(function(){ 

    if (num == 40) { //max 40 steps

            clearInterval(gInterval);
            //what do with ghosts after?

        } else {

            $ghosts.removeClass('step'+(num-1)).addClass('step'+num);
            num++;

        }

}, 250);
```

Not a good solution and doesn't take advantage of CSS3 capabilities, but when has IE ever made that easy anyway?